# How to make menu close before redirecting to website section

Tags: javascript, html, css, domcontentloaded

I have a JQuery working code that is closing the navigation before redirecting to the right section. I want to change it for pure javascript. Do you have any ideas how to make it happen? I've searched many topics but didn't find it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.menu-mobile a').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
 closeNav();

  setTimeout(() => {
     const nextPage = e.currentTarget.href;
    window.location.href = nextPage;
  },1000) // set the time here in milliseconds    
})
});
```

Additionally, I would like to change `$(document).ready` to javascript.
Is it valid replacer?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
  //code
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, something like following, you just need `closeNav();` function.

```js
document.querySelector(".link").addEventListener("click", function(e)  { 
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.href)
  //closeNav();
  setTimeout(() => {
    const nextPage = e.target.href;
    window.location.href = nextPage;
  }, 2000)  
});
```

```html
<div class=".menu-mobile ">
  <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting weird errors. First, when I included this code in seperate JS file. I was getting errors with cannot read null addEventListener. When I replaced it to the bottom of my html body, the script isn't using this eventListener at all.

Comment: did you included `closeNav()` function?

Comment: Yes, I posted a snippet below in the comment. My closeNav() is a function toggling betweeen classes. It is used also when opening the menu.

Answer (score 1):

- you don't need to use $(document).ready in vanilla / pure javascript.
- Porting the same logic implemented above in js would be something like this:

## HTML

```
<button click=handleClick(e)>click me </button>
```

## JS

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
// To prevent event bubbling
e.preventDefault();
window.location.href = e.currentTarget.href

}
```

Comment: Thah means that all JS functions will work after the DOM content is fully loaded anyway?

Comment: JS will start running only when DOM content is loaded. In jQuery we have to use document.ready because  in jQuery, its library get's loaded first and then our js files, that is why we use document.ready there

Comment: Here i'm getting "e is not defined" error... :/

Comment: The only time you don't need to wait for the document to be ready is when the `<script>` tag is at the end of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for your jQuery code to be written in vanilla JS? If so:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
document.querySelector('.menu-mobile a').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  closeNav();

  setTimeout(() => {
    const nextPage = e.currentTarget.href;
    window.location.href = nextPage;
  }, 1000); // set the time here in milliseconds    
});
});
```

I used [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: I have added a snippet of my code below in the comment. It's stll not working